# Select x random elements from an array (that contains nested arrays) and no more than one from each nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm new to programming, but have learnt enough HTML & CSS to create my handmade blog [onlyrss.org](https://onlyrss.org/), and now I've tried my [first JavaScript "app"](https://onlyrss.org/posts/my-first-javascript-app.html). The app does most of what I need it to do i.e. pick x random exercises from an array. But, some of the exercises are "alternatives" and I don't want more than one of them in the output e.g. ring pull-ups OR bar-pullups, OR chin-ups,  500m row OR 250m row etc.

My guess is I need nested arrays in my array that group together the alternatives, and then the code only ever picks 1 option from each nested array (guess it makes sense if every entry in the main array was a nested array, even if it only has a single value for now?). To be frank, this is well past my abilities at the moment, hence my request for help.

Here's the link to the [code on Codepen](https://codepen.io/dbssticky/pen/MWQqXXE), but the code is also shown below:

```
// get the slider value
    function getNumber(){
        let input = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
      return input
    }

//triggered by the main button: set the number of exercises to "n"
    function myFunction() {
    let n = getNumber() 

//clear the list of any existing exercises
    document.getElementById("todays_exercises").innerHTML = "";

//define the array
    let all_exercises = [ 
      " air squats ×40",
      " skip ×200",
      " burpees ×20",
      " row 500m",
      " pull-ups ×10",
      " finger board pull-ups ×10",
      " ring pull-ups ×10",
      " sit-ups ×40",
      " press-ups ×25",
      " lunges ×20",
      " curls ×15",
      " ring rows ×12",
      " assisted ring dips ×10",
      " ring push ups ×10",
      " power snatch ×10",
      " power clean ×20",
      " power clean & jerk ×15",
      " hanging leg raises ×20",
      " bench press ×10",
      " calf raises ×20",
      " plank 20s",
      " dips ×20",
      " row 250m"
    ];

//Set the max value of the slider (with id=userInput) to the # of elements in the array
    document.getElementById("userInput").setAttribute('max', all_exercises.length);

// shuffle the full array
    function shuffleArray(array) {
        for (let i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
            const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
            [array[i], array[j]] = [array[j],  array[i]];
        }
    }

// pull out the first n values from the shuffled array and display as ordered list
    shuffleArray(all_exercises);
    all_exercises.slice(0,n).forEach(e => {
        todays_exercises.innerHTML =  todays_exercises.innerHTML + '<li>' + e + '</li>' ;
    });
    }
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nested arrays would do the trick. You can use your shuffle function to shuffle the nested array as well.

```
// similar exercises are grouped
const all_exercises = [
    ["pull-ups","bar-pullup"],
    ["power-snatch","power-clean"],
]


all_exercises.slice(0,n).forEach(e => {
    shuffleArray(e); // shuffle the nested array
    // choose the first element using e[0]
    todays_exercises.innerHTML =  todays_exercises.innerHTML + '<li>' + e[0] 
     + '</li>' ;
});
}
```

Here is a [working codepen.](https://codepen.io/andreasaanestad/pen/dymbyLp)

Comment: That works a treat, cheers! It's exactly what I needed, and only required tiny changes, thanks for your time!

Comment: and here's the final result https://onlyrss.org/apps/circuits.html